# Type for O(1) lookup

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

What should `SomeType` in the code below be to include anything that has an O(1) lookup such as  `Set` and `KeysView` w/o doing a long `Union` type?

```
def f(fast_lookup: SomeType[int]):
    return 0 in fast_lookup
```

Comment: What do you include in "_anything_"? Do you have a closed list in mind?

Comment: No. I only use `Set` and `KeysView`, but I would guess that there's others. If possible, the type would extend to also include custom classes that support O(1) lookup using default syntax.

Comment: You may want to rewrite your question for clarity.